# How to decode this: 0x7f100161?

Tags: decode

How to decode this type of code: 0x7f100161?
I found it in a xml file as an id of a tag with the mame: time.

.                                                 .

Comment: In order to decode something you need to know its encoding. Whats the encoding of above literal??

Comment: This is just a hexadecimal number. My browser "translates" it to `2131755361` in decimal.

Comment: Could be reference, e.g. a memory address https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_address ... In this case you can't decode it. (In this case, in order to understand it you need to find the referenced object.)